# How to preserve node ids between db.schema calls

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-algorithm

Starting with a bigger picture, I'd like to apply some functions from Graph Algoritms plugin to the database schema.

I'm using this query through Neo4j Browser:

```
CALL algo.betweenness(
  "CALL apoc.meta.graph() YIELD nodes UNWIND(nodes) AS n RETURN id(n) AS id",
  "CALL apoc.meta.graph() YIELD nodes UNWIND(nodes) AS n MATCH (a)--(b) RETURN id(a) AS source, id(b) AS target",
  {graph:'cypher', write: true})
```

but it responds with error:

```
 Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `algo.betweenness`: Caused by: org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to load NODE with id -998.
```

I've checked and both `apoc.meta.graph()` and `db.schema()` do not preserve node id's between queries. Moreover, a query:

```
CALL apoc.meta.graph() 
YIELD nodes 
UNWIND(nodes) AS n 
RETURN n.name
```

returns only `null` values even though `RETURN n` would return nodes with `name` and `count` properties (visible in Graph and Table/Text views from the Browser).

So my question: is it possible to persist ids assigned to nodes through schema discovery functions and use them in graph algorithms as shown in the above query? If it's not possible, could you suggest other approach for my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The nodes and relationships returned by the meta graph don't really exist, they are a manifestation of meta data from Neo4j, using virtual graph elements to provide a temporary graphical view of that data. You might take a look at some [node functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#node-functions) from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), some of which are capable of access properties of virtual nodes and relationships. Otherwise, what are you attempting to do with this?

Comment: First of all I'd like to calculate some metrics from Graph Algorithms on the nodes returned by `db.schema`, particularily a `betweenness` measure. Is there a way to store this *virtual* graph to let's say separate database? For now I'll try with `uuid` virtual node function according to your comment.

Comment: @InverseFalcon so I've checked the docs and managed to get `name` from `apoc.any.properties(n).name` but still the `id` problem remains. Is there a way to solve it like this:
1) Query `db.schema` and tranform it so that nodes contain `name` and `id` (either from `id()` or `uuid()` func)
2) Use the results of this query in `betweenness` algorithm (using some keyword), hence saving the previous in memory between the calls?
Alternatively do you know of a method for storing results of `db.schema` a new database? Thanks a lot for help